# jQuery AJAX call in PHP resulting in 401 errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-401

I've got a intranet site running under IIS7 using PHP 5+, jQuery 1.5.1, Windows Authentication for SSO capabilities.

Whenever I make an AJAX call to another PHP script, Firebug returns a 401 Unauthorized error, retries and succeeds (still reporting the 401). This sometimes results in pages taking 5+ seconds to load! I've found this topic all over the place for ASP but nothing for PHP. Please help if you can and let me know if you need any more settings info.

Answer (score 0):

After much more research, I've discovered that the best method for avoiding this costly vicious 401 cycle is to tap into your IIS server. Individually set authentication for each script to be called as an AJAX function to "Anonymous". This can be done by manually editing the applicationHost file or through the IIS Management Interface.